# Are these small hairy leaves first true leaves of my rudbeckia seedlings?

Tags: seedlings, perennials

Are these small hairy leaves first true leaves of these seedlings?

The plant in question is [Rudbeckia hirta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudbeckia_hirta).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, they look quite hairy at this stage - image in this link, but scroll down to find it https://wimastergardener.org/article/prairie-sun-black-eyed-susan-rudbeckia-hirta/

Comment: Very informative article, lots of diverse details on rudbeckia, one of better articles on any specific plant that I've read, thanks!

Comment: In case you are interested, see    http://latin-dictionary.net/definition/22197/hirtus-hirta-hirtum    .... It seems "hirta" is Latin for "hairy".